# Check if radio button exists jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am setting a radio button's checked state to true based on a certain value;

```
 var radioValue = data.Activity.Answer == "Please add your answer" ? "valueA" : data.Activity.Answer;
$("input[name=optionRadio" + currentIndex + "][value=" + radioValue + "]").attr('checked', true);
```

What will be the best way for me to check that that radio button actually exists on the slide before hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `length` of the jQuery object to find it out:

```
if($("input[name=optionRadio" + currentIndex + "]").length > 0 ){
     // Radio button actually exists...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `length`

```
if($("input[name=optionRadio" + currentIndex + "][value=" + radioValue + "]").length)
```

Note, however, that if the radio button does not exist, calling `attr` will have no effect and will not result in any errors. So if your only goal is to set the attribute, you will not need the `if` statement.